# Swift button not working?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel

I want a button to change a labels text when pressed, but when I press on the button it does nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
@IBAction func face1(sender: AnyObject) {

    abbi.text = "face 1 works"

}
```

Comment: have you confirmed your code is running? Perhaps the action is not hooked up properly in IB?

Comment: You probably haven't hook up the button to the action from your storyboard.

Comment: When diagnosing problems with a stereo or TV system, the rule of thumb is "check the wiring". When diagnosing problems with user interfaces in iOS, the rule of thumb is "check the IBOutlet and IBAction connections." (The "wiring", if you will.) If you don't know how to check the outlet connection, you can set a breakpoint in your code or add a print statement to verify that your code is being called.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine Ahmed Onawale is correct. You probably don't have your button hooked up correctly. This sometimes occurs when you delete and recreate objects. 
To check to see if it is hooked up correctly right click on your button in the storyboard; both the actual button or right clicking the button in the 'view controller scene' will work. You should see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SSUw.png) if it is working correctly.

You can fix it by deleting your button reference in your code and control-dragging the button back to the code to recreate it. It should re-enable the connections to work properly.